# How to read from txt file line and print arrays of strings and integers

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, readfile

I am reading from a text file a specific line defined by a user input with `if(nameLine.contains(inputFileName)){` I am trying to print an array of names and array of numbers from that line. Could anyone help me out with how to do so? Do I have to create 2 different methods or can I do it all in main? I only know how to work with one `Array` in one code with `while loop`, but I am not sure how to have it all combined. Thank you for your help!

> My code is not finished, but this is how it looks so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the State name: ");
    String inputFileName = in.next();
    String names = "pplnames17.txt";

    List<String> namearr = new ArrayList<String>();

    File namesFile = new File(names);
    Scanner stateSearch = new Scanner (namesFile);

    //print title
    String line0 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("pplnames17.txt")).get(0);
    System.out.printf("%s in %s", line0, inputFileName);

    while(stateSearch.hasNextLine()){
        String nameLine = stateSearch.nextLine();
        if(nameLine.contains(inputFileName)){
            System.out.printf("\n%s",nameLine);
        }
    }
```

> This is a partial of my `Array` code for `String`, which I had it after a `while loop`

```
    while(stateSearch.hasNextLine()){
    namearr.add(stateSearch.nextLine());
}
String[] arr = namearr.toArray(new String [0]);
System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because "a @*** type of error" is not a useful problem statement.  Please [edit] your question to include the *exact* error message, and none of the cursing.

Comment: the type of error was not a concern in here at all. @JoeC  -- [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302 is what the error says. My code is unfinished because I have never worked with this kind of exercise. I was trying my best

Comment: Then [edit] your question to remove what's not related to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this isn't the greatest solution, here is a potential solution that you could build upon/tidy up.

Basically, read in your file, loop through each line, if the line contains the user input, split each `string` on that line, check if text or numeric, and add to the relevant array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> intArr = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Enter the State name: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFileName = in.next();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("pplnames17.txt"));

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String nameLine = sc.nextLine();
            if (nameLine.contains(inputFileName)) {
                String[] inputs = nameLine.split(" ");
                for (String input : inputs) {
                    if (isNumeric(input)) {
                        intArr.add(Double.parseDouble(input));
                    } else {
                        nameArr.add(input);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!nameArr.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(nameArr);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No names found");
        }
        if (!intArr.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(intArr);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No numbers found");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I tested it and my text file was like this:

> abc def ghi 12 55 jkl mno pqr
>
> joe jack mary 1 2 james 4
>
> paul jim kim bob 45 othername
>
> bill yu will gill 455 Paulo

User input of `mary` gave an output of:

> [joe, jack, mary, james]
>
> [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]